# Zurb Modal doesn't allow autocomplete

Tags: zurb-foundation

We are using a modal popup in Zurb which has a form. We can't get to have the autocomplete on. 
This is the code:

```
<div class="form">
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/test_autoresponder" class="new-test-email" id="new_responder_test_email" method="post">
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="WEN2mD0aQRH2GOFBFt8UvkNwhVjRm9sox3gU1iAr7Sk="></div>
<input id="responder_test_email_responder_id" name="responder_test_email[responder_id]" type="hidden" value="100">
<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
<label for="responder_test_email_email_address">Enter the email address(es) to which you would like to send your test. Separate multiple email addresses with a comma.</label>
</div>
<div class="large-12 columns">
<textarea id="responder_test_email_email_address" name="responder_test_email[email_address]"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
<button class="btn" name="button" type="submit">Send
</button></div>
</div>
</form>
```

Ideas?

Comment: The autocomplete form works outside the Zurb Modal ?

Comment: @general03 yes! It's here: www.moonmail.io the send test email modal in the campaigns list view

Answer (score 1):

**$scope.list = ["TEST 1","TEST 2".... etc];**

`$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source:$scope.list,
    appendTo: "#divId"  //Div id 
});`

```
<div class="small-6 columns end" id="frmCriteria">
    <input type="text" id="auto">
</div>
```